# Apache Pig Error - Why it don't accept all the columns in chararray

Tags: apache-pig, hdfs

I've the following Pig Script:

```
   I'm trying with this:
```

Source_Data = LOAD '/user/cloudera/Source_Data/' using PigStorage('\t','-tagFile'); 
Data_Schema = FOREACH Source_Data GENERATE (
(chararray)$1 AS Date, 
(chararray)$2 AS ID, 
(chararray)$3 AS Interval, 
(chararray)$4 AS Code,
(chararray)$5 AS S_In_Activity,
(chararray)$6 AS S_Out_Activity,
(chararray)$7 AS C_In_Activity,
(chararray)$8 AS C_Out_Activity,
(chararray)$9 AS Traffic_Activity);
STORE Data_Schema INTO '/user/cloudera/Source_Data/New_Data/' USING PigStorage('\t');

Here is a row of my source data:

> 11300 1387926000000    76     1.8190562337403677        0.9613115354827483        330.0372865843317554633          0.1161754442265068633     11.04195619825027733

But I'm getting error when I execute the code but If I remove the last part to define the schema it gives me successfully. Note that the first column was inserted by the Pig Statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically answer yourself the question in the last sentence. You can not declare schema when using STORE operator. According to the [official doc](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#STORE):

```
STORE alias INTO 'directory' [USING function];
```

In your case it will be simply:

```
Data = LOAD '/user/cloudera/Source' using PigStorage('\t','-tagFile'); 

Data_prestage = FOREACH Data GENERATE (
(chararray)$1 AS Filename, 
(chararray)$2 AS CCode, 
(chararray)$3 AS SCode, 
(chararray)$4 AS In_Act,
(chararray)$5 AS Out_Act,
(chararray)$6 AS In_Act1;

STORE Data_prestage INTO '/user/cloudera/Source/Data2/' USING PigStorage('\t');
```

Also if you do not plan on doing any manipulation with the data you might think of using STREAM instead.

Comment: Many thanks for your response!

It still gives me an error probably I need to use Python to do modify this data in HDFS

Comment: I have modified an answer. When you use tagFie option the order of the columns is switched so I had to start count from $1 instead of $0. Also remove whitespace and replace it with tab('\t'). Also try to run your job with -ColumnMapKeyPrune option.